# Update VBA to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to retrieve and update rows in Excel/SQL and found this script which works but I tried to make it update as soon as I enter the "existencia" value instead of hitting run on the update macro, found the Worksheet change function but I'm not sure how to add it to this macro.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; data source=LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Inventario;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    con.Open


    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    'The assumption is that the data on the Excel sheet is listed from a1 Cell, including fields.
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Productos SET Existencia='" & vDB(i, 4) & "' WHERE id_cod=" & vDB(i, 1) & " "
        cmd.Execute
    Next i

    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Careful, what you have is open to injection; you should be parametrise your statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Worksheet_Change event to do a lot of things, but I have never ever used Worksheet_Change to update data in a SQL Server table.  This doesn't really make sense, if you think about it.  You can make all kinds of changes in an Excel file, all day long.  People do this all the time.  When you are totally done with your updates, changes, or whatever, you can push the data to a table in a database.  You should not do this intermittently.  Otherwise, you will have to do all kinds of cleanup in your database table(s).  You don't want to create this kind of overhead for yourself.